# Not able to upload the audio file along with the data to the server through nougat version of android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-7.0-nougat

I'm not able to upload the audio file to the server through the nougat version of android, The audio is recorded through the media recorder and saved on the device.Here is the code, the same is working for all the versions of android except nogat ,though in nogat the media is recorded and saved in device , but it not being uploaded on the server.

```
private void submitRecording() {
    CallLogsModel.idle++;
    final String filename = "file.MP3";
    final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename;

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    String json = "";

    try {

        String uniquecode = PreferenceConfigration.getPreference(Constants.PreferenceConstants.UNIQUE_CODE);
        String token= UtilityMethods.tokenValue();
        Log.e("Token",token);
        jObject.put("uniquecode",uniquecode);

        jObject.put("lead_id", CallLogsModel.leads);
        jObject.put("duration",getAudioDuratiion());


        jObject.put("date_of_call", getDate());
        jObject.put("time_of_call",startTime);
        jObject.put("device", PreferenceConfigration.getPreference(Constants.PreferenceConstants.DEVICE).toString());
        jObject.put("token", token);
        Log.e("formed",jObject.toString());
        if (path.equals("") || path.equals(null) || path.equals("null")) {
            jObject.put("aboutphoto", "nophoto");
        }
        else
        {

        }
        json = jObject.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Log.e("raisetic", json);
    OKhttpConnect.doPosttRequestWithMutipart("all_data", "attachment", "http://armsenterprise.com/api-new/kre-app/save_call_log.php", json, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename, new HTTPcallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Log.e("Failure",e.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(final String response) {

            if (response != null && !(response.isEmpty())) {
                final JSONObject jsonObject;
                try
                {
                    CallLogsModel.idle++;
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.e("ResponseCall", response);


                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                ((Activity) MainActivity.context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error in submission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
    ((Activity) MainActivity.context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.context, "Raising Ticket ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });




}
```

Comment: You can now look at the code